# json.stringify slice array to word

Tags: angularjs

I use `JSON.stringify(data);` to return json

here is my code

```
var data;
programService.query({
    id: $routeParams.id
    }, function (result) {
    data = { 'program': result };
    data= JSON.stringify(data);
    $scope.setPagingData(data,page,pageSize);
    });

$scope.setPagingData = function(data, page, pageSize){
    var pagedData = data.slice((page - 1) * pageSize, page * pageSize);
    $scope.myData = pagedData;
    $scope.totalServerItems = data.length;
    if (!$scope.$$phase) {
        $scope.$apply();
    }
};
```

json data

```
{programId:1, 
 programName:project1, 
 programContent:content1, 
 programStartDate:2012-01-01, 
 templateId: "1"}
```

and the result will be p , r, o...

not a programId, 1, programName, project1.....

any ideas?

Comment: JSON.stringify turns an object into a string.

Comment: how can I return the json array?

Comment: Just cross-referencing your two questions, you asked nearly the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18071510/use-slice-function-to-slice-json-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but let me just point out some things in your code that could potentially point you in the right direction.

**First**, your JSON data (which I assume you mean as the `result` from your server:

```
{programId:1, 
programName:project1, 
programContent:content1, 
programStartDate:2012-01-01, 
templateId: "1"}
```

is pretty decently mal-formed. Double-quotes around both keys and values is proper JSON format (values that are numbers don't need quotes).

---

**Second**, assuming your JSON data is indeed how you want and expect it to be, in your callback function:

```
...
    }, function (result) {
      data = {
        'program': result
      };
      ...
    });
...
```

`result` is a ***STRING*** (since JSON is simply a text-based serialization format and is always a string), meaning

```
data = {
  'program': result
};
```

results in `data` looking like a JS object like this:

```
{ 'program' : '{programId:1, programName:project1, programContent:content1, programStartDate:2012-01-01, templateId: "1"}' }
```

***Perhaps you meant to convert the JSON into a native JS object***, in which case `JSON.parse(result)` is what you are looking for.

```
data = {
  'program': JSON.parse(result)
};
```

`data` now looks like a JS object like this (**assuming your JSON is well-formed, otherwise the parse function will break**):

```
{
    "program" : {
        "programId" : 1,
        "programName" : "project1",
        "programContent" : "content1",
        "programStartDate" : "2012-01-01",
        "templateId" : "1"
    }
}
```

---

**Third**, back to your callback function:

```
...
    }, function (result) {
      ...
      data= JSON.stringify(data);
      $scope.setPagingData(data,page,pageSize);

    });
...
```

`data= JSON.stringify(data);` converts the given data into a ***JSON string***. If this is what you intend, then carry on!

---

**Fourth**, in your `$scope.setPagingData` function,

```
$scope.setPagingData = function(data, page, pageSize){
    var pagedData = data.slice((page - 1) * pageSize, page * pageSize);
    $scope.myData = pagedData;
    $scope.totalServerItems = data.length;
    if (!$scope.$$phase) {
        $scope.$apply();
    }
};
```

the `.slice` function and `.length` attribute are both part of the Array prototype. This means if your passed in `data` is a JS object, `.slice` will throw a "has no method slice" error and `.length` will return undefined.