# Use slice function to slice JSON object

Tags: json, angularjs

I want to slice a JSON array, but get the following error:

> Object # has no method 'slice'

The following is my code:

```
$scope.getPagedDataAsync = function (pageSize, page, searchText) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var data;
        programService.query({
          id: $routeParams.id
        }, function (result) {
          data = {
            'program': result
          };
          data = JSON.stringify(data);
          data = JSON.parse(data);
          $scope.setPagingData(data,page,pageSize);

        });
    }, 100);

};

 $scope.setPagingData = function(data, page, pageSize){
    var pagedData = data.slice(0, 3);
    $scope.myData = pagedData;
    $scope.totalServerItems = data.length;
    if (!$scope.$$phase) {
        $scope.$apply();
    }
};
```

JSON data:

```
{programId:1, 
 programName:project1, 
 programContent:content1, 
 programStartDate:2012-01-01, 
 templateId: '1'}
```

I want to slice the array as follows: programId, 1, programName, project1, ...

I am so confused , please help.

Comment: Objects don't have a `slice` method.

Comment: The slice method for an array object, in your case `data` is not an array it is an Object

Comment: How can I convert the data to array?

Comment: Just cross-referencing your two questions, you asked nearly the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18071001/json-stringify-slice-array-to-word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var data = {
    programId:1, 
    programName:'project1', 
    programContent:'content1', 
    programStartDate:'2012-01-01', 
    templateId: '1'
}
var array = [];
for(var key in data){
    if(!data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        continue;
    }
    array.push(key, data[key])
}
console.log(array, array.slice(0, 4))
```

Comment: While this likely works on all browsers today, there is no guarantee of iteration order.  The OP may be better off explicitly creating the array if that is the desired result.

Comment: @dc5 yes, you are right... the spec does not guarantee the order of keys

Comment: Thanks for every body